# SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate

Tags: tls, authentication, certificate-authority

Running the following command:

```
curl -v --key client_key.key --cert client_cert.crt <some url> -u <username>
```

I get the following response:

```
*   Trying XX.XXX.XXX.X...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <somedomain.com> (XX.XXX.XXX.X) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate
```

I'm a little unsure of how to pursue identifying what the issue is here. The client certificate I'm providing is signed by GlobalSign:

```
CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa
```

The server is meant to verify that the cert is from a trusted authority and forward it on. I was under the impression for a trusted certificate authority this would just work.

I know it's not a lot to go on but any idea of how I could approach identify the issue would be really helpful.

TIA.

Comment: *"The server is meant to verify that the cert is from a trusted authority and forward it on. I was under the impression for a trusted certificate authority this would just work."* - the exact use case is not clear but usually servers don't just accept any client certificate issued by some public CA but have more specific requirements, like a certificate issued by a specific CA, with specific information in the subject etc

Comment: @SteffenUllrich In that case my comment doesn't apply. I deleted it. Good to learn something new.